# How to set leaftlet searchbox position with css (leaflet.extra package)

Tags: css, r, shiny, leaflet

Leaftlet allows limited controls positions such like "topleft" or "topright". How can I set leaftlet searchbox position with css in Shiny (Search from leaflet.extra package) ? 
Here is a minimal example :

```
      library(leaflet)
      library(leaflet.extras)
      library(shiny)

      ui <- fillPage(leafletOutput("mymap"))

      server <- function(input, output, session) {
        output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
          leaflet() %>%
            addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldStreetMap) %>%
            addSearchOSM()
        })

      }

      shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I set the searchbox in any position ? (for example top center? )

Browser Inspection gives me some elements :

```
 <a class="search-button" href="#" title="Search using Google Geocoder"     style="outline: none;"></a>
```

What I tried with css :

```
      library(leaflet)                  
      library(leaflet.extras)
      library(shiny)

      ui <- fillPage(
       tags$head(tags$style(
         HTML('leaflet-search-button {margin-top: 100px;}
      '))
         ),
        leafletOutput("mymap")
        )

      server <- function(input, output, session) {
        output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
          leaflet() %>%
            addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldStreetMap) %>%
            addSearchOSM()
        })

      }

      shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `leaflet-control-search` selector. `!important` is needed so that you can overwrite the default margin.

```
tags$head(tags$style(
  HTML('.leaflet-control-search {
    margin-top: 100px !important;
  }')
))
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Ok! Thank you  for helping

Comment: @ GyD not able to position the search box to the center of map. just the button is moving.